# PhoneStateListener is not working in android lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, phone-state-listener

I've developed a radio app where i need to pause radio when incoming/outgoing phone calls comes. I've used PhoneStateListener which is working fine in all android version except in lollipop. Here is the code that i have used to handle phone calls. I've tried both setStreamVolume and setStreamMute methods but both seems not working in lollipop. Please some body help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

```
                PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state,
                        String incomingNumber) {
                    switch (state) {

                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING: // Incoming
                                                                // call:
                                                                // Pause
                                                                // music
                        if (Globals.isPlayerRunning) {
                            curVolume = audioManager
                                    .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                            audioManager.setStreamVolume(
                                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);
                            audioManager.setStreamMute(
                                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
                            isServiceMuteByCall = true;
                        }
                        break;

                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE: // Not in
                                                            // call:
                                                            // Play
                                                            // music
                        if (isServiceMuteByCall) {
                            isServiceMuteByCall = false;
                            audioManager.setStreamMute(
                                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
                            audioManager.setStreamVolume(
                                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, curVolume,
                                    AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
                        }
                        break;

                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:// A call
                                                                // is
                                                                // dialing,
                                                                // active
                                                                // or
                                                                // on
                                                                // hold
                        if (Globals.isPlayerRunning) {
                            curVolume = audioManager
                                    .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                            audioManager.setStreamMute(
                                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
                            audioManager.setStreamVolume(
                                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);
                            isServiceMuteByCall = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

                }
            };

            if (mgr != null) {
                mgr.listen(phoneStateListener,
                        PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
            }
```

Comment: the question is, is the phonestatelistener not working or the audioManager? Have You tried some logs to get sure that the phone states are not read?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs - phonestatelister is not getting fired

Comment: @ramesh6233 I'm experiencing the same thing, did you find any solution to your problem?

Comment: @drisse, yes, we've found a solution for this. Please see my answer below.Please let me know if this works for you,  thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution to above issue. This can be solved using BroadcastReceiver.

Create a class which extends BroadcastReceiver and inside onreceive method check for phone states like below.

```
public class TelephonyManagerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         if (TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

             String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

             if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state)) {
                 //stop the player or mute the audio here
             } else if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(state)) {
                 //start the player or unmute the audio here
             } else if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK.equals(state)) {
                 //stop the player or mute the audio here
             }
        }   
    }   
}
```

after this add above broadcast receiver in manifest file.

```
<receiver android:name="com.radioapp.util.TelephonyManagerReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

and ensure that you request this permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: i have tried your code but i get this error "not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE from pid=23532, uid=10107"